# SQL to calculate discount for suppliers based on certain condition

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I have a discount table which lists the suppliers who are eligible for discount and the discount %. This discount is also based on the item category. I want to list all suppliers, items they supply and for each item if they are part of the category, the applicable discount. There is also a special case where if category is missing in the discount table, the supplier is eligible for discount across all items they sell. In my below example supplier 4 and 5 are eligible for discounts on all items they sell

Here is the code i tried in MySQL, but this applies discount to items not eligible for discounts -

```
SELECT asl.supplier_id,i.item_id, i.cat,d.discount
from all_supplier asl left outer join discount d on asl.supplier_id = d.supplier_id
left outer join supplier_item si on d.supplier_id = si.supplier_id
left outer join item i on si.item_id = i.item_id;
```

This is the actual result i get, note for supplier 1 and item 3, there should be no discount.
Also there are items for supplied by supplier which is not listed in discount. Items supplied by supplier 6,7 are missing from this list

[image]

Sample Dataset

all_supplier
[image: all_supplier]
discount
[image: discount]
item
[image: item]
supplier_item
[image: supplier_item]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leveraging a more complex join condition for the discount table. This one should work:

```
SELECT
    s.supplier_id,
    i.item_id,
    i.cat,
    d.discount
FROM all_supplier s
LEFT JOIN supplier_item si
    ON si.supplier_id = s.supplier_id 
LEFT JOIN item i
    ON i.item_id = si.item_id
LEFT JOIN discount d
    ON d.supplier_id = s.supplier_id 
    AND (d.cat = i.cat OR d.cat IS NULL)
ORDER BY s.supplier_id, i.item_id
```